# Display different prices in each of the item of the array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, collections

I have three different **string array**:

```
var firstArrayString: [String] = ["01:00", "02:00", "03:00"]
var secondArrayString: [String] = ["04:00", "05:00", "06:00"]
var thirdArrayString: [String] = ["07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00"]
```

And i have **price** for each **string array**:

```
var priceFirst: Int = 1000
var priceSecond: Int = 1500
var priceThird: Int = 2000
```

I use **collectionCell** for display all my **array strings**.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var allArrayStrings: [String] = firstArrayString + secondArrayString + thirdArrayString

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return allTimeintervalArray.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTimeCell

    cell.timeLabel.text = allTimeintervalArray[indexPath.item]

    // how can I display different prices in each of the rows of the array?

}
```

I want to display approximately so in my **collectionCell**:

```
01:00 - 1000
02:00 - 1000
03:00 - 1000
04:00 - 1500
05:00 - 1500
06:00 - 1500
07:00 - 2000
08:00 - 2000
09:00 - 2000
10:00 - 2000
```

**How can i show it?**

I have tried many combinations of **if** and **switch**, but nothing helped, maybe I wrote something wrong. Please help me.

Comment: which is your allTimeintervalArray ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to create array of tuples (price and the string value):

```
let allArrayStringsAndPrices: [(price: Int, value: String)] =
    firstArrayString.map({ (price: priceFirst, value: $0) })
    + secondArrayString.map({ (price: priceSecond, value: $0) })
    + thirdArrayString.map({ (price: priceThird, value: $0) })
```

And use it:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allArrayStringsAndPrices.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTimeCell
    cell.timeLabel.text = "\(allArrayStringsAndPrices[indexPath.row].value) - \(allArrayStringsAndPrices[indexPath.row].price)"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your method works for me. It was the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array of `String`, you can use an array of tuple `(String, String)`, that contains both the time intervals and their respective price, i.e.

```
var firstArrayString: [(String, String)] = [("01:00", 1000), ("02:00", 1000), ("03:00", 1000)]
var secondArrayString: [(String, String)] = [("04:00", 1500), ("05:00", 1500), ("06:00", 1500)]
var thirdArrayString: [(String, String)] = [("07:00", 2000), ("08:00", 2000), ("09:00", 2000), ("10:00", 2000)]
```

Then in your `collection view`, you can use it like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTimeCell
    cell.timeLabel.text = allTimeintervalArray[indexPath.item].0
    cell.priceLabel.text = allTimeintervalArray[indexPath.item].1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be much off if you separated your collection view into sections (three in this case), one for each of your arrays.

```
var allArrayStrings = [[String]]()
var allPrices = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    allArrayStrings = [firstArrayString, secondArrayString, thirdArrayString]
    allPrices = [priceFirst, priceSecond, priceThird]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allArrayStrings.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allArrayStrings[section].count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTimeCell

    cell.timeLabel.text = "\(allArrayStrings[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]) - \(allPrices[indexPath.section])"

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statement in printing cell for array counts:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return firstArrayString.count + secondArrayString.count + thirdArrayString.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTimeCell

    if indexPath.item < firstArrayString.count {
        cell.timeLabel.text = "\(firstArrayString[indexPath.item]) - \(priceFirst)"
    }    
    else if indexPath.item < (firstArrayString.count + secondArrayString.count) {
        cell.timeLabel.text = "\(secondArrayString[indexPath.item - firstArrayString.count]) - \(priceSecond)"
    } 
    else {
        cell.timeLabel.text = "\(thirdArrayString[indexPath.item - firstArrayString.count - secondArrayString.count]) - \(priceThird)"
    } 

}
```

Comment: Separating each array into its own section (as shown in my answer) eliminates the need for all of this extra math and `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

I think this could help for small amount of data.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as? BookingTimeCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }

    let currentString = allTimeintervalArray[indexPath.item]

    if firstArray.contains(currentString) {
        print("Current Array Value:", currentString, "And Price :", firstPrice)
    } else if secondArray.contains(currentString) {
        print("Current Array Value:", currentString, "And Price :", secondPrice)
    } else if thirdArray.contains(currentString) {
        print("Current Array Value:", currentString, "And Price :", thirdPrice)
    } else {
        print("None of the arrays contain", currentString)
    }
}
```